# How to generate a highcharts stacked bar sparkline?

Tags: javascript, jquery, highcharts

I have three values I want to plot in a horizontal stacked bar chart, but I am not sure how to combine the stacked nature of the [demo here](https://jsfiddle.net/gh/get/library/pure/highcharts/highcharts/tree/master/samples/highcharts/demo/bar-stacked/) with the sparkline in the [demo here](https://jsfiddle.net/gh/get/library/pure/highcharts/highcharts/tree/master/samples/highcharts/demo/sparkline/). When I load the page, nothing is shown in the sparkline column.

```
$('[data-sparkline]').each(function(){
    var data=$(this).data('sparkline').trim().split(',').map(Number);
    $(this).highcharts('SparkLine', {
      series: [{
        data:data ,
        type: "bar"
      }],
        plotOptions: {
          series: {
              stacking: normal
          }
        }
    })
});

<tbody id="tbody-sparkline">
{% for x in data %}
<tr>
    <td><a href="team/{{ x[0] }}">{{ x[0] }}</a></td>
    <td>{{ x[1] }}</td>
    <td>{{ '{0:0.2f}'.format(x[2]) }}</td>
    <td>{{ '{0:0.2f}'.format(x[3]) }}</td>
    <td>{{ '{0:0.2f}'.format(x[4]) }}</td>
    <td>{{ '{0:0.2f}'.format(x[5]) }}</td>
    <td data-sparkline="{{ '{0:0.2f}'.format(x[3]) }}, {{ '{0:0.2f}'.format(x[4]) }}, {{ '{0:0.2f}'.format(x[5]) }} "></td>
</tr>
{% endfor %}
</tbody>
```

Any help would be appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'll address how to modify their demo into sparklines with stacked bar. It's still all just "plain Highcharts", but some modifications must be done. To stack you need to support multiple series. To do this in their example, heres a modified `<td>`:

```
<td data-sparkline="71, 78, 39, 66 ; 87, 44, 74, 41 ; 58, -10, 1, 16"/>
```

And altered options:

```
chart: {
  type: 'bar',
  // ...
},
plotOptions: {
  series: {
    stacking: 'normal',
    // ...
  }
}
```

A modified `doChunk`, which converts the `arr` to `series` instead of `data`, since there are multiple series:

```
function doChunk() {
  var time = +new Date(),
      i,
      j,
      len = $tds.length,
      $td,
      stringdata,
      arr,
      series,
      chart;
  console.log(series);

  for (i = 0; i < len; i += 1) {
    $td = $($tds[i]);
    stringdata = $td.data('sparkline');
    arr = stringdata.split('; ');
    series = [];
    for(j = 0; j < arr.length; j++) {
      series.push({
        data: $.map(arr[j].split(', '), parseFloat),
        pointStart: 1
      });
    }


    chart = {};

    $td.highcharts('SparkLine', {
      series: series,
      tooltip: {
        headerFormat: '<span style="font-size: 10px">' + $td.parent().find('th').html() + ', Q{point.x}:</span><br/>',
        pointFormat: '<b>{point.y}.000</b> USD'
      },
      chart: chart
    });

    n += 1;

    // If the process takes too much time, run a timeout to allow interaction with the browser
    if (new Date() - time > 500) {
      $tds.splice(0, i + 1);
      setTimeout(doChunk, 0);
      break;
    }

    // Print a feedback on the performance
    if (n === fullLen) {
      $('#result').html('Generated ' + fullLen + ' sparklines in ' + (new Date() - start) + ' ms');
    }
  }
}
```

See [this JSFiddle demo](https://jsfiddle.net/5tuhd8v0/2/) of the modified Sparkline example (look at Alabama). Note that this example format does not support chart type specification as it uses all the `arr` for series processing.

Comment: That was helpful, thank you. I still need to figure out why the series are showing stacked right to left instead of left to right, and why when there is only one in each series the stack fully justifies and adjusts the graph, making it somewhat useless when comparing to other sparklines in the table. But I'll explore that in options now that I have working graphs.